# W3C validator complains about input tags

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I don't know what is wrong with these html tags:W3C validator insists the button is not accepted:

```
<div id='mainDiv'>
    <div id='div1' >
    <form id='SampleFormID' action=''>
    <input type='button' id='downloadSample' ><br>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

W3C error:

```
    Line 144, Column 49: document type does not allow element "INPUT" here; 
    missing one of "P", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "PRE", "DIV", 
    "ADDRESS" start-tag


I'm using <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">.
```

Comment: You can also look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253312/why-wont-this-xhtml-form-validate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the input-element inside a div for example.

```
<div id='mainDiv'>
    <div id='div1' >
    <form id='SampleFormID' action=''>
        <div><input type='button' id='downloadSample' ></div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason you have to do this is because `input` elements need to be inside block-level elements, such as a `div`. [Just in case that wasn't clear.](http://nerdmeltla.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/the-more-you-know.jpg)

Comment: This is the case for [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM). However, in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element), forms do not expect block level elements anymore but are flow elements (inline elements).

Answer (score 2):

The validator is assuming [HTML 4.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) Strict. If you replace your current DOCTYPE declaration with `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`, it will validate.

Comment: Or use the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<div id='mainDiv'>
    <div id='div1' >
    <form id='SampleFormID' action=''>
    <p><input type='button' id='downloadSample' /></p>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@stewe

Best Answer, The input tag needs any cover code whether it be `<div>` or `<p>`.
But best one is `<div></div>` as it doesnot format the input tag from general output or universal ones of `<p>` tag.